# How to utilise my kv string in the calculation of a predetermined equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.5, kivy-language

So here's a grossly simplified version of my code so far:

```
Builder.load_string("""
<TabSys>:
    TextInput:
        id: lhv_entry
        multiline: False
        size_hint: .3, .08
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .152, "center_y": .47}
        hint_text: 'Latent heat of vaporization'
        font_size: 30
        font_name: "Arial"
        font_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        background_color: (.3, .3, .3, 1)
        hint_text_color: (1, 1, 1, .5)
        cursor_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        selection_color: (1, 1, 1, .3)
        foreground_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        disabled_foreground_color: (1, 1, 1, .5)

    Button:
        id: calculate_psc
        text: "[color=e6e6e6]Calculate[/color]"
        font_name: "Arial"
        font_size: 30
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        size_hint: 1, .1
        markup: True
""")
```

I don't want to inundate you with too much code, just assume that I've got all the needed libraries and all the main loop sorted below the close of the string. My question is this: how do I, in my proper code which makes use of many text inputs per tab, get pressing the button which is id'd as calculate_psc to take the values from the text inputs, and then perform a single preset operation on them?